# Can not get pip3 on ubuntu Linux to install a library

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to create a secure chat using secrets as an import but when I go to install this is all i get from it is

`Collecting secrets
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement secrets (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for secrets`
python 3 version 3.5.1-3
I am using this command to install it on Ubuntu 16.04.`sudo pip3 install secrets`any one have a clue? I know this library exists its in the python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Comment: Can't you just `import secrets` already?

Comment: I can not Ubuntu says its not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't comment on this i'm creating an answer to try and help you.

Secrets seems to be a part of the Standard Library, which means there is no need to pip install it, it should already be importable.

Since this Library is new in Python 3.6 there is a need for you to have said Python version or else you won't be able to use it.

Check your Python version by typing the following into your console.

```
python -V
```

Comment: its python 3.5.1-3

Comment: You might want to upgrade to 3.6 then, because Secrets cant be installed/imported in a version below 3.6

Comment: The command line says that python is at its newest version?? python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3)

Comment: [See this Question on how to Upgrade your Python to 3.6](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569)

Comment: Thanks so much for the by the way.

Comment: @JackRipper If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.